# call current controller action within button click from partial view in MVC3 view razor view engine

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a view with including partial view (Partial view from different controller that call  `@{ Html.RenderAction("DebitHeadConfigure", "HeadDisplayConfigure");}`) now i need a action against Button click which button come from partial view

Note : Currently if i use submit type button then it call my main controller action

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem isn't in your button, but in the form that you are submitting. Make sure that you specify action and controller in a form within your partial view.

For example:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionToCall", "ControllerContainingAction", FormMethod.POST)) {
     <p>
         My Form
     </p>
}
```

References:

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.formextensions.beginform(v=vs.108).aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460344(v=vs.108).aspx